# how portable are unaligned read / write?

Tags: c++, memory, struct

let's say I have a struct of type `A` that is POD, and a `void` pointer `p`.

Can I safely cast `p` to a pointer to `A`, then read/write to the `A` structure pointed by `p` ?
Is it guaranteed to work everytime, even if the alignment of `A` is 8 and p points to an odd memory adress? (worst case)

I am not concerned about performance issues, I just want to know if it's supposed to work according to the standard and / or if it's portable enough on mainstream platforms.

edit : I'm also interested to know if there's any difference depending on x86 / 64 bits architecture

Thanks!

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Kamil Kozar : how so ? The answer below says it actually is

Comment: You can do what you propose if and only if `p` contains a value obtained from converting a valid pointer to an object of type `A` to void pointer.

Comment: It will work on x86, but PowerPC and RISCs architectures in general will simply crash/"alignfault". Dunno about other architectures. From the language point, I believe accessing a variable without the proper alignment is simply forbidden in c++.

Comment: @sbabbi : thanks ! is there any way to know for sure if for a given architecture it will work ? I'm specifically wondering about 64 bits windows / linux

Comment: @lezebulon Have you considered testing it?

Comment: @EJP : I have tested it with success on windows x86 / 64 bits, except I have no proof that it's supposed to be working. Also I'm concerned about linux 64 bits

Comment: @lezebulon Google/wikipedia for it.

Comment: @sbabbi  : the purpose of my question is exactly to find this info. googling for it basically tells me "its works" without giving a reference

Comment: @lezebulon Yeah sorry, I would have written an answer if I knew how to get the complete information :p

Comment: @lezebulon It also depends on the actual required alignment size. For instance with arm you can load/store to an unaligned 4 byte address, but you can not load/store to unaligned 8 byte address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can cast a pointer to class A to a class B.

Essentially, you are telling the compiler to use stencil `class B` when referring to the memory location of the `class A` variable.

Generally, this is not safe because the values at the locations will have different meanings and positions.

Usually, this type of casting is used for interpreting a buffer of `uint8_t` as a structured object.  Another usage is when there is a `union`.

So the term *safe* depends on the context that the operation is used in.

**Edit 1:  Alignment**
Most modern processors can handle alignment issues.  The processor may require more operations to fetch the data, which will slow down the performance.

For example with a 16-bit processor, a 16-bit value aligned on an odd address will require two fetches (since it only fetches at event addresses):

```
+----------+----------------------------+  
|  address | value                      |  
+----------+----------------------------+  
|  16      |  N/A                       |  
+----------+----------------------------+  
|  17      | 1st 8 bits of 16-bit value |  
+----------+----------------------------+  
|  18      | 2nd 8 bits of 16-bit value |  
+----------+----------------------------+  
|  19      |  N/A                       |  
+----------+----------------------------+
```

Since the processor only fetches values at even addresses, fetching the value will require 2 fetches.  The first fetch at address 16 obtains the first 8 bits of the 16-bit variable.  The second fetch obtains the second 8 bits of the variable.

The processor also has to perform some operations to get the bits in the preferred order in one "word". These operations will also negatively affect the performance.

Comment: Indeed in my case I have a buffer of uint8_t. By safe, I mean is it guaranteed that I can store my structure at an unaligned adress and then read it back from this adress later on, while keeping the data integrity?

Comment: As long as the contents are not changed, you can read it many times.  You want to refrain from multiple accesses like this.  I recommend copying the bytes from the `uint8_t` into a properly aligned structure, then refer to the structured variable.  This will be more efficient than referring to the `uint8_t` buffer each time.  Also, beware of padding in a structure.  *The size of a structure may not be the sum of the size of the members.*  This is due to alignment padding.

Comment: The ARM Cortex M3 (common in microcontrollers) can handle 32-bit reads and writes of unaligned data, *but* its instructions that read/write multiple 32-bit words at once cannot.  If code receives `struct POINT {Int32 x,y;} *pt;` and performs `pt->x=23; pt->y=47;`, a smart compiler might load 32 and 47 into registers and then perform a two-register store.  One may thus end up with code that will seems to work regardless of pointer alignment, until one day the compiler decides to optimize things differently and things break.