C++ - placement of int at non-integer multiple of 4
as far as I know integers for example are placed in memory at integer multiples of their size. Can I access a set of bytes starting at non-integer multiple of sizeof(int) via a pointer as an int? The code below seems to work, producing
Size of int: 4
native byte order: LSB
0  127  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
Is it guaranteed, or not? Thanks.

#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <bit>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cerr<<"Size of int: "<<sizeof(int)<<endl;
    if(std::endian::native == std::endian::little) cerr<<"native byte order: LSB"<<endl;
    else cerr<<"native byte order: MSB"<<endl;

    const int N = 3;
    int array_int[N];
    memset(array_int,0,sizeof(int)*N);
    std::byte *array_byte = (std::byte*)array_int;

    int *ptr = (int*)(array_byte+1);
    *ptr = 127;

    for(int i=0; i<N*sizeof(int); ++i) cerr<<(int)(array_byte[i])<<"  ";
    cerr<<endl;

    return 0;
}


The above example compiles and runs as expected naively

You can: it's called non-aligned reads/writes - but only if your target computer supports it, and not all do. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64501099/159145 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28996867/159145

Whenever you do a C-style explicit conversion (the casting you do for array_byte) it should be taken as a sign that you're probably doing something wrong. It might still work and be supported by your system, but there might be other problems somewhere else (perhaps bad design?).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39908990/1387438

It's undefined behaviour to access an unaligned object. That doesn't mean it has to break, a conforming implementation can consistently work in the manner that you expect.

Use memcpy to copy the bytes that you are interested in to an int variable in a portable manner. The compiler will elide the calls to memcpy when possible.


std::byte *array_byte = (std::byte*)array_int;
int *ptr = (int*)(array_byte+1);
*ptr = 127;


This is undefined behavior.
The issue is that you are accessing an object of type int, but ptr does not point to such an object.
It is impossible for an int to exist at an address where it would be misaligned (see [basic.align] p1):

An object type imposes an alignment requirement on every object of that type; [...]

Even if an int object existed at the address array_byte + 1, you would arguably need to std::launder it because "walking" up the object representation of array_byte doesn't give you a pointer to the int at that address; it only gives you a pointer to the bytes of the object representation.

The code below seems to work, [...]

Undefined behavior often gives off the appearance of working, but it doesn't really work.
It might happen to "work" because you're compiling for x86_64, where misaligned reads are possible.
On another architecture, the CPU could raise an exception, just like for division by zero.
With another compiler, your code could just be turned into gibberish or optimized out completely.
